# Showing ip addresses in android programming

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm trying to get the available networks' ip addresses in an android device and show them as Toast in the screen. The trouble is that when i upload this to my android device(Sony xperia z c6602) it shows "dummy0" and the ip address of my internal modem 3 times.

i have several questions.

if there is only data network available why it's ip address is showing up 3 times. why not just once.

what is the meaning of "dummy0"

why it's showing only the internal modem's ip address (why not wifi,bluetooth?)

```
private class GetIP implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface>ins=NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while(ins.hasMoreElements()){
                in=ins.nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress>inadds=in.getInetAddresses();
                while(inadds.hasMoreElements()){
                    inadd=inadds.nextElement();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast t=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),in.getDisplayName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            Toast tv=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),inadd.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();
                            tv.show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}



    }
}
```